# Joining two tables displays NULL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I want to get all data from Invoice table added with `Firstname` and `Lastname` from table `usersDetail`.

My query is returning data from Invoice table but with `NULL` value on `Firstname` and `Lastname`.

Can you please assist ?

**Table Fields**

---

Invoice table = `InvoiceId, Date, CreateByUser(Guid), Vehicule`

UserDetail table = `UserId(string), FirstName, Lastname`

*CreateByUser = UserId*

```
var invoiceContext = _context.Invoices.ToList();

var usersDetail = _userManager.Users.Select(x => new ApplicationUser { Id = x.Id, FirstName = x.FirstName, SurName = x.SurName }).ToList();



var result = from      invoice in invoiceContext
                       join
                       usrDtl in usersDetail
                       on invoice.CreateByUser.ToString() equals usrDtl.Id into tempstorage
                       from dx in tempstorage.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new InvoiceViewModel
                       {
                           Id = invoice.InvoiceId.ToString(),
                           Date = invoice.Date,
                           Vehicle = invoice.engine,
                           
                           FirstName = (dx != null) ? dx.FirstName : "NULL",
                           SurName = (dx != null) ? dx.SurName : "NULL"
                       };
```

**Class Model**

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Vehicle { get; set; }

    public Guid CreateByUser { get; set; }

    public int TotalInvoice { get; set; }

    public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }
}



public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public Guid CreateByUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TotalInvoice { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }
    
    public string Vehicle { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: dx != null Wrong - > use same Dx.FirstNameIsNull()?

Comment: Are you sure that that are matches for `invoice.CreateByUser.ToString() equals usrDtl.Id`? Leading or trailing spaces may be involved. Either way, it's better to show the class model so we know what the question is about.

Comment: @GertArnold  I edited the above post to add class models.

Comment: And what about the matches?

Comment: @GertArnold Regarding the match table, I added InvoiceViewModel. Not sure if it is what you're looking for.  Also thank you for trying to assist me.

Comment: I mean: are you sure that `invoice.CreateByUser.ToString() equals usrDtl.Id` is `true` anywhere?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm sure. `invoice.CreateByUser` is a GUID when user create an invoice, it stores the current userId who created the invoice into this field `invoice.CreateByUser`.

Comment: @GertArnold  I tried to remove the InvoiceViewModel type from the select new, and guess... it's works fine. So It works only if you remove the InvoiceViewModel from select, and make it an anonymous type.  Not sure why ?? I just tried it now. So why is that ?

Comment: @GertArnold  very sorry, it's my own mistake saying that from my post that **My query is returning data from Invoice table but with NULL value on Firstname and Lastname.**.  I got NULL value when I debug because it's a long list of 50 datas so, when i debug, i only walk through 10-15 first data to check... so I wasn't looking at the whole list of data.

Comment: When I started the project there were not requirement about first and lastname, so more than 40 data on the list has no firstname and lastname from the db has the field firstname and last name was added yesterday morning, but the invoice table was created 2 weeks ago so it's normal to find them empty... only the last 5 data from the list which has firstname and lastname and the latter is at the bottom of the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = (from invoice in invoiceContext
            join usrDtl in usersDetail
             on invoice.CreateByUser.ToString() equals usrDtl.Id into usrDtlj 
             from usrDtl in usrDtlj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new InvoiceViewModel
              {
              Id = invoice.InvoiceId.ToString(),
              Date = invoice.Date,
              Vehicule = invoice.engine,
              FirstName = usrDtl.FirstName==null? "NULL":usrDtl.FirstName,
              SurName = usrDtl.SurName==null? "NULL":usrDtl.SurName
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: *Why* would adding `ToList` change anything? They clearly have output already. Suggestions to try something are good for comments anyway, not for answers.

Comment: I'm getting `System.NullReferenceException`  **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** exactly on `usrDtl`

Comment: I'm getting System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exactly on from usrDtl in usrDtlj.DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: @Serge It works only if you remove the InvoiceViewModel from select, and make it an anonymous type.  Not sure why ?? I just tried it now and works fine with InvoiceViewModel removed.  So why is that ?

Comment: @Serge very sorry, it's my own mistake saying that from my post that **My query is returning data from Invoice table but with NULL value on Firstname and Lastname.**.  I got NULL value when I debug because it's a long list of 50 datas so, when i debug, i only walk through 10-15 first data to check... so I wasn't looking at the whole list of data.

Comment: When I started the project there were not requirement about first and lastname, so more than 40 data on the list has no firstname and lastname from the db has the field firstname and last name was added yesterday morning, but the invoice table was created 2 weeks ago so it's normal to find them empty... only the last 5 data from the list which has firstname and lastname and the latter is at the bottom of the last.

Comment: So in the end this was not the answer. Just to note that.

Comment: @User456 You are very welcome.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = (from invoice in invoiceContext
         join usrDtl in usersDetail
         on invoice.CreateByUser.ToString() equals usrDtl.Id into usrDtlj 
         from usrDtl in usrDtlj.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new InvoiceViewModel
          {
          Id = invoice.InvoiceId.ToString(),
          Date = invoice.Date,
          Vehicule = invoice.engine,
          FirstName = usrDtl==null?"":usrDtl.FirstName??"" ,
          SurName = usrDtl==null?"":usrDtl.SurName??""
          }).ToList();
```

try this. it will work without error.